# how to create literal based query in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I created one function for create expression

```
def test(operator1, operation, operator2):
    return literal_column(operator1).op(operation)(operator2)
```

Now when I call it with

```
test(1, '=', 1)
```

then it works

But when I pass

```
test('abc', '=', 'abc')
```

Then it gives error that abc is not a column.

I tried to convert it

```
def test(operator1, operation, operator2):
    return literal_column(operator1, String).op(operation)(operator2)
```

But that was not working.

This will work if i call with

```
test("'abc'", '=', 'abc')
```

Is there any way, to get the type of operator1 and on that bases we can create literal_colum which will be map to same type of content ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

any literal value can be converted to an expression construct:

```
from sqlalchemy import literal_column, bindparam


# ? = ?, 1 will be bound
bindparam(1) == bindparam(1)

# " 1 = 1", literals rendered inline (no quoting is applied !!)
literal_column(str(1)) == literal_column(str(1))
```

Comment: When i use bind params like bindparam(1)==bindparam(1) then i get `FROM users
WHERE %s = %s
2011-09-16 10:56:24,588 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (None, None)` 
and when i convert it in literal_column('1')==literal_column('1') i get 
`FROM users 
WHERE 1 = 1
2011-09-16 10:59:49,835 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
`
This will work for integer but for string it give error and convert int 
`FROM users
WHERE abc = abc
2011-09-16 10:59:49,835 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
`

Comment: Its assumed you're using the mechanics of execute() here to work with the clause construct. If you're just doing str(clause) and then using that, then yes you lose the bind param values but you're kind of going outside the usual usage patterns of the API.   If you want to use literal_column with a string, you have to securely quote it.  I'd advise against doing that and I'd stick to the patterns at http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/tutorial.html as much as possible.

Comment: Thx for your help. If get any better idea then please post. I will add quote with string variable. :)